# Display All simple products of a grouped product as list view in magento product page

Tags: php

i had a catalog with 29 products and when the catalog is clicked its products are to be displayed as list view as all grouped products are displayed, is there any extension for this or any help is to be appreciated

Comment: I am not getting your question. Explain it in bit detail.

Comment: Can you be more clearer about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ,you want to fetch using  all simple product

```
$Product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID) 
$SimpleColl= $Product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getAssociatedProducts($Product);
```

This  $SimpleColl is given all simple prodouts

```
foreach($SimpleColl as $simple){
  var_dump($simple)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a category using `catalog->Manage Categories` under Default Category.

If you have added products in the website you can directly associate that product with the category using tab Category Products and selecting the product you want to display on frontend.

Make the category `Is Active -> 'YES'` and `Included In Navigation Menu -> 'YES'`

If you haven't added the product on website. Add a new product and associate it to the category from there.